Input function in the Jupyter Notebook
#correct email: sonu.yadav19997@gmail.com
#correct password: 1234

email = input("Enter your email")
password = input("Enter your password")
if email == "sonu.yadav19997@gmail.com" and password == "1234":
    print("Welcome")
else:
    print("Incorrect user input")

I wrote a program with input function. Unfortunately, I ran the program after writing the first two lines with input function before I had written other lines of code. The code worked and asked for user input. I didn't put anything in the user input boxes and instead completed writing the code. When I ran the complete code, the code moved to the next cell instead of asking for user input. I tried copying and pasting the entire code to a new cell and deleting the old cell but that didn't work. I created a new ipykernel file and wrote the same code. The code worked in a new file and asked me for the user input.
What's the problem?

On what platform are you trying to do this?

A good habit for working with Jupyter can be to regularly restart the kernel and run your code again. As you found, copying your code to a new notebook or duplicating the notebook itself, can often get you past oddball glitches like that. I'd caution you to even keep copies of your code on you local machine, maybe even separate from even your .ipynb files, and you should be able to recover & pivot a little better. Plus, use of input() is a bit archaic. I know you see it a lot in tutorials and such but is a legacy thing from the command line and not really compatible with the modern ...

 nature of Jupyter in modern browsers. There are other ways to handle getting information into a running Jupyter session that you'll be using more as you go forward.

Thank you so much, @Wayne! Restarting the kernel worked!

@SamuNémeth I'm writing this code on Jupyter Notebook (chrome browser).
